# Arrays in a class

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a media register that allows the user to submit a book or a movie which gets stored in an array. This is what I have so far:

```js
let titleInput = document.getElementById("title");
let authorInput = document.getElementById("author");
let pagesInput = document.getElementById("pages");
let title2Input = document.getElementById("title2");
let directorInput = document.getElementById("director");
let runTimeInput = document.getElementById("runTime");

let displayBox = document.getElementById("display");
let displayBox2 = document.getElementById("display2");

class Media {
  constructor(title) {
    this.title = [];
  }
}

class Book extends Media {
  constructor(title, author, pages) {
    super(title);
    this.author = [];
    this.pages = [];
  }
  insert() {
    title.push(titleInput.value);
    author.push(authorInput.value);
    pages.push(pagesInput.value);

    clearAndShow();
  }
  clearAndShow() {
    titleInput.value = "";
    authorInput.value = "";
    pagesInput.value = "";

    displayBox.innerHTML = "";
    displayBox.innerHTML += "Title: " + title.join(", ") + "<br/>";
    displayBox.innerHTML += "Author: " + author.join(", ") + "<br/>";
    displayBox.innerHTML += "Pages: " + pages.join(", ") + "<br/>";
  }
}

class Movie extends Media {
  constructor(title, director, runTime) {
    super(title);
    this.director = [];
    this.runTime = [];
  }
  insert2() {
    title2.push(title2Input.value);
    director.push(directorInput.value);
    runTime.push(runTimeInput.value);
    clearAndShow2();
  }
  clearAndShow2() {
    title2Input.value = "";
    directorInput.value = "";
    runTimeInput.value = "";

    displayBox2.innerHTML = "";
    displayBox2.innerHTML += "Title: " + title2.join(", ") + "<br/>";
    displayBox2.innerHTML += "Director: " + director.join(", ") + "<br/>";
    displayBox2.innerHTML += "Run Time: " + runTime.join(", ");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMedia(event, 'Book')">Book</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMedia(event, 'Movie')">Movie</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Book" class="tabcontent">
      <form id="tabcontent" name="myForm" class="bookContainer" onsubmit="return(validate());">
        <label for="Title">Title:</label>
        <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Book title">
        <small class="error"></small>
        <br>
        <label for="Author">Author:</label>
        <input id="author" type="text" placeholder="Author's name">
        <small class="error"></small>
        <br>
        <label for="Pages">Pages:</label>
        <input id="pages" type="text" placeholder="Amount of Pages">
        <small class="error"></small>
        <br>
        <button onclick="insert()" id="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div id="display">
        <h3> </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Movie" class="tabcontent">
      <form name="form2" class="movieContainer" onsubmit="return(validate());">
        <label id="" for="Title">Title:</label>
        <input id="title2" type="text" placeholder="Movie title">
        <small class="error"></small>
        <br>
        <label for="Director">Director:</label>
        <input id="director" type="text" placeholder="Director's name">
        <small class="error"></small>
        <br>
        <label for="runTime">Runtime:</label>
        <input id="runTime" type="text" placeholder="Runtime of movie">
        <small class="error"></small>
        <br>
        <button onclick="insert2()" id="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div id="display2">
        <h3></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I assumed this was the correct way to do this but I end up getting scope errors I believe. Please take a look at the code pen here: https://codepen.io/nstersleep/pen/GRMRzpo?editors=0011

My question is, how would I make the Arrays that hold all the user values work in a class? This is the first time I've done something like this!

Comment: Hi! *"Please take a look at the code pen here"* Please use the **on-site** runnable example feature: Stack Snippets, the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. *(I tried just copying and pasting the code int he question into a Stack Snippet, but pressing Submit didn't work, so presumably there's more to it.)*

Comment: Why does the `Media` constructor accept a `title` parameter it doesn't do anything with?

Comment: *"but i end up getting scope errors i believe"* What makes you think that? What errors are you seeing? (Please use copy and paste to provide the error messages.)

Comment: Just a best practice note: Parallel arrays like `title`, `author`, and `pages` are fragile, it's too easy to modify one of them and not the others, making things mismatched. Instead, do a single array of objects with properties for the title, author, and pages.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your input! The error i got was Uncaught "ReferenceError: insert is not defined" so i assume i put the insert method in the wrong place?

Comment: Please pay attention to the other comments and update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). For instance, your HTML uses a function called `openMedia` that is nowhere in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented, the question is incomplete, but the main issue is you're missing `this.` when referring to properties and methods in the class. JavaScript doesn't have implied `this` like Java and C# do, it must always be explicit. So for instance, in `Book`'s `insert`, you need

```
this.title.push(titleInput.value);
^^^^^
```

Without it, you're trying to use an in-scope variable (`title`) that doesn't exist.

That's also true for method calls like `clearAndShow`.

But some other things jump out as well:

- You have constructor parameters you're not using for anything. Just remove them.
- I wouldn't tie the classes to the input elements by having the classes close over the input element variables. Instead, pass the input elements to use into the class constructor.
- Parallel arrays like your `title`, `author`, and `pages` are fragile, it's too easy to modify one of them and not the others, making things mismatched. Instead, do a single array of objects with properties for the title, author, and pages.
- `Book` and `Movie` are singular, but you're using them to hold multiple books and movies (plural). If you wanted to do that, it would make more sense to use either the plural (`Books`, `Movies`) or some name indicating they're a container (`BookStore`, `MovieStore`).
- There isn't any reason `Movie`'s `insert` and `clearAndShow`. methods need to have different names from `Book`'s.
- `Book` and `Movie` don't really serve much of a purpose. After all, they're really just arrays. Instead, I'd have a `Book` class that represents a single book (with `title`, `author`, and `pages` properties) and a `Movie` class that represents a movie (with `title`, `directory`, and `runtime` properties). (They could inherit from a `Media` class that has `title` if you like.) Then just keep an array of `Book` instances and an array of `Movie` instances.

Here's a quick sketch of that last point:

```
class Media { // If you want it, it doesn't add much value with just the one property
    constructor(title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}

class Book extends Media {
    constructor(title, author, pages) {
        super(title);
        this.author = author;
        this.pages = pages;
    }
}

class Movie extends Media {
    constructor(title, director, runTime) {
        super(title);
        this.director = director;
        this.runTime = runTime;
    }
}

const books = [];
const movies = [];

// Adding a book:
books.push(new Book(titleInput.value, authorInput.value, pagesInput.value));

// Adding a movie:
movies.push(new Movie(titleInput.value, directorInput.value, runTimeInput.value));
```

Answer (score 0):

On submit, You are trying to call insert function which is out of scope because insert is defined within Book class and not in global scope.

```
<button onclick="insert()" id="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Add a caller function which you can call from html. This caller function will build the object of the book class then call insert() of Book object.

a sample could be a below -

```
function submitBook() {
    var book =  new Book(titleInput);
    book.insert();
    book.clearAndShow();
  }
```

then call it from HTML as below

```
<button onclick="submitBook()" id="submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Another point is - please use *this* keyword to assign/read values from the variables in your functions as mentioned in first answer. for example -

```
this.title.push(titleInput.value);
```